# How to implement function which take ether and give token?

Tags: solidity

I need to make function which doing next

1. User type amount of tokens which he wants to buy and press buy
2. Smart contract takes his ether and give him token

How I can do this?
Because I  know only one way, when you type amount of ether, not tokens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assumin that yours is a tokensale contract. If that is the case then you can do calculation on the frontend side of how much ether is required to buy X amount of your tokens. Like, let's say your 1 token costs 1 ether then if user inputs 500 token to buy, then amountOfEtherRequired = 1 * 500 ~ 500 ether.
So, send these values through web3js/ethers.js. And send amountOfEtherRequired as callValue.